How to Import Data from Haver Analytics into R?
I am trying to obtain data from Haver using R, I know that it is possible using Stata, here is the example code:
set haverdir \\user\Haver\DLX\DATA
import haver (Q003GDPC /// OECD
              Q028GDPC /// Euro area
              Q111GDPC /// US
              Q112GDPC /// UK
              Q142GDPC /// Norway
              Q144GDPC /// Sweden
              Q146GDPC /// Switzerland
              Q156GDPC /// Canada
              Q158GDPC /// Japan
              Q193GDPC /// Australia
              )@OUTLOOK ///
              Q023YER@EUDATA /// for back-calculation of Euro area
              , clear

Is there any way to do the same only in R ?

What is the file format in Haver? It would be helpful if you can share a toy data in Haver format here. Or you can share it on a github repository and share the link here.
